# fetchSize,PartitionColumn,LowerBound,upperBound in Spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Hi I am new to Spark sql and got an assignment to  write a spark job to load data from jdbc using Spark sql and load it in cassandra.

I was trying to refer some old spark code from my existing project.
Here is the configuration mentioneD:

```
Total Record Count in JDBC table :233400
```

Here is the configuration mentioned in spark code:

```
LowerBound:0
Upper bound:100000
numPatrition:20
fetchSize:100
```

As per the article: [How to operate numPartitions, lowerBound, upperBound in the spark-jdbc connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51516822/how-to-operate-numpartitions-lowerbound-upperbound-in-the-spark-jdbc-connectio)

numPatrition:  Number of concurrent connections that can be made to DB at a time.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE partitionColumn < 5000 or partitionColumn is null

SELECT * FROM table WHERE partitionColumn >= 5000 AND <10000

SELECT * FROM table WHERE partitionColumn >= 10000 AND <15000

SELECT * FROM table WHERE partitionColumn >= 15000 AND <20000

...

SELECT * FROM table WHERE partitionColumn >= 95000
```

But in the reference code, I am not able to understand what role fetch size will play here. How my data will be partitioned (Considering the record count is same as mentioned:233400)
Also once, upper bound is reached, does that mean the last partition will have :
(totalRecord - upperBound) number of records?

Please help me to understand this concept

Comment: upperBound is like `limit` so you will not get the whole data. fetchSize is how many data will you load at once.

Comment: @Lamanus are you trying to say that in my scenario where i have record count as: 233400,i should mention the upperBound= 233400??